# How to get attributes from fineuploader handler?

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

I have the following piece of code

```
<div class="cv-uploader" id="customid">Upload CV</div>

$('.cv-uploader').fineUploader({

        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: '/process',
            params:{ elementId:$(this).attr('id') }
        },
        //some other code
});
```

I need to send in the request parameters the ID of the element that triggered fineuploader. I tried $(this).attr('id') but it wont work.

Please help

Thanks
Sergiu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a general JavaScript question then a Fine Uploader question.  The problem is that you are misunderstanding how context works in JavaScript.  In your code, `this` will always refer to the `window` object.  Obviously, this is not what you want.

You can either do this:

```
$('.cv-uploader').fineUploader({

        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: '/process',
            params:{ elementId:$('.cv-uploader').attr('id') }
        },
        //some other code
});
```

...or this:

```
$('.cv-uploader').fineUploader({

        debug: true,
        request: {
            endpoint: '/process'
        },
        //some other code
})
    .on("submitted", function(event, id) {
        $(this).fineUploader('setParams', {elementId: $(this).attr('id')}, id);
    });
```

The latter example is possible as Fine Uploader's jQuery plug-in wrapper sets the context of any jQuery event handlers you bind to a Fine Uploader instance as the jQuery object that represents that element.

However, I would recommend the first approach as it is more efficient.

Comment: Great ! tried them both and they're working like charm ! Many thanks :)